# Upgrade my 2017 Dell XPS13 from Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade

I never upgraded to 18.04.  How, exactly, should I proceed to upgrade to 20.04 or 22.04?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Comment: I'm involved with QA & did my last installs of *xenial* for [16.04.7](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-16-04-7-lts-released/) and often use the same box/setup for varying releases; using a *Upgrade via re-install* often so my music/music-player etc. survive the re-install  (that's a *testcase* for Lubuntu for one)..  Yes it's possible to *upgrade via re-install* but that's assuming desktop (not server!) & if it was data I valued, I'd do more homework than I do for QA-test installs (*I don't expect problems; only worried with why if there are problems*).

Comment: My point is I'd likely use *upgrade via re-install* which is boot the ISO/media you want to install/upgrade into, re-use existing partitions but do **NOT** format any (it's the lack of format for "/" which triggers this type of install) & go. It'll note your *manually installed* packages, erase system directories (this is a problem for server apps, but not desktops apps), install from media, IF internet is available will re-install *manually installed* packages noted earlier if available in Ubuntu repositories, without touching any user config/file/setting IF no format was selected.

Comment: If you're using encrypted folders (eg. encrypted HOME) that is NOT an option on later (18.04 or later) installs so the installer won't know how to deal with that, so add the package required for that prior to starting the installer & you're good to go (worked for me multiple times!), but this install is QA-tested only with Ubuntu repository software, so you do your own homework if using 3rd party packages.

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to upgrade from 16.04, 18.04, to 20.04, you can follow the instructions from this [link](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-using-command-terminal/)

It'd probably be easier to do a fresh installation of the latest version. And you might want to consider backing up your data using an external drive instead of using the one in your machine.

Comment: A fresh install is certainly the way to go with this one. A lot has changed since 16.04 